# @Route condition request.isXmlHttpRequest except when kernel.debug == true

Tags: symfony

I need to get my controller to process only ajax request except when the parameter `kernel.debug` is true.

Here is my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/research/{pattern}",
       condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest() and context.getMethod() in ['GET']"
public function researchAction($pattern)
{
    // 
}
```

How do I add `or kernel.debug == true` to condition statement?

Comment: `isXmlHttpRequest` is not reliable, better create some parameter or just a separate endpoint